# `Tensor OpKernelContext::mutable_input(int index, bool lock_held)`

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to write a custom op, and wish to modify the input tensor. I browsed the code and found the above-mentioned method in `op_kernel.cc`

However the return type is a value, not a reference. I tried modification on this, and the effect is not reflected in the input.

If return by value is intended, then why does the author increment the reference count using `record_tensor_reference(tensor)`?.

(p.s. I have re-factored the code so I do not necessarily need to change input in the op. But still I look forward to an answer)

Answer (score 0):

If input data is on CPU, and operator is registered on GPU, tf would copy input to GPU memory, so return pointer of mutable_input is pointed to GPU's part. So the effect cannot be reflected in the input.